# Broadleaf-commerce: CustomPersistenceHandler of Custom Entity in Admin module

Tags: spring, broadleaf-commerce

I am trying to use Custom Persistence Handler as mentioned in [tutorial on broadleaf commerce's Admin module](http://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/core/current/tutorials/admin-customization-tutorials/calling-an-external-service-using-a-custom-persistence-handler).

In `update()` method after retrieving the entity from dao, we try to merge the updated values in entity object, by calling `helper.createPopulatedInstance(adminInstance, entity, adminProperties, false);`.

However, the merged object does not contain the newly set property. However that property is visible in `entity`object.

What am I missing here ?

Comment: Are there any validation errors on the Entity object after executing this method? Any exceptions thrown? What is the type of field that you are trying to set and is it based on a ToOne relationship?

Comment: No there are no validation errors. I debugged into it step by step. The adminInstance (retrieved using primary key from dao) does not contain the property that is updated, however the same is visible in the "entity" object. The type of field is Boolean and it is not based on any ToOne relationship.